# How can I determine the order of parameters for x-www-form-urlencoded in Microprofile RestClient?

Tags: java, resteasy, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

### Use Case

I have following rest client

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "service")
public interface Service {

  @POST
  @Path("Invoice")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  Response request(@QueryParam("instance") String instance, @BeanParam Input input);

}
```

`Input` is a class which is a POJO including properties like

```
public class Input {

  @FormParam("title")
  public String title;

  @FormParam("description")
  public String description;
```

### Problem

The request to the API is working fine, **but** in my case, the order of properties does matter (The reason behind that is something, I cannot answer at the moment, sorry).

So sending `title=Test&description=Testdescription` is different to `description=Testdescription&title=Test`.

### Other solutions I have tried

1. With `Form` instead of POJO: No data is send to the server

```
  @POST
  @Path("Invoice")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  CustomResponse requestForm(@QueryParam("instance") String instance, @BeanParam Form form);
```

2. With `Entit<Form>`: No data is send to the server

```
  @POST
  @Path("Invoice")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
  CustomResponse requestForm(@QueryParam("instance") String instance, @BeanParam Entity<Form> form);
```

### Assumption

I found out, that `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.processors.FormProcessor` is using a `HashMap` internally. I think that is exactly the problem, because there is no guaranteed order. Is my assumption correct?

### Question

How can I work around that and always provide the same order for the API using the Microprofile Rest Client.

### Workaround

It works with a `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient` invoking like

```
 Response response = target
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .post(Entity.form(form));
```

Comment: probably the http standard doesn't guarantee order, so the fact that it works with the jboss resteasy client is luck. the fact that the server relies on ordering is probably not conform with the specs.

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me, see:

```
@POST
@Path(value = "/auth/realms/{realm}")
@Consumes(APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
    AuthenticateResponse authenticate(@PathParam("realm") String realm, MultivaluedMap<String,?> params);
```

Try to use MultivaluedMap